# Get the number of running containers from inside a container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an app with several containers, `nginx`, `postgres` and several instances of a `rack` based app, built with `docker-compose`. How can I let the `rack-app` access to the number of running containers?
I installed `curl` and `net-tools`in the `rack-app` and tried things without success.

Comment: What exactly did you try and why didn't it work? Can you give a bit more background on _why_ you want to do that?

Comment: Why? Let's say firstly learn, then I want to do an animation about load balancing, so I may want to know the number, so it's not about how to avoid doing this. Then I tried netstat but it showed me only Postgres with TCP, not nginx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Docker Engine API: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/

Retrieve container information with curl (change version, if necessary):

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/v1.40/containers/json
```

In order access the API from within your containers, you need to mount the Docker socket of the host:

```
 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: I tried and the json looks promising. Let's see if I can run this from my app and work on it.

Comment: Remember that if you can use the host's Docker socket, you can very easily root the entire system.  I would not recommend adding this for "nice to have" diagnostics given the security implications.  If you do have it, be very very very careful with basic security things.

Comment: ok, thanks, so this means that there is no way to get this info safely

Comment: Walk around ? The Postgres container must has a connection with each app. Maybe I can run system command `netstat -t | wc -l` by Postgres and save this into a table ?   Now I would need the app to query the database and trigger this query and return. Is this workable?